# Index Tuning Question

Tags: sql-server, performance, index-tuning, execution-plan, query-performance

I have the following query:

```
SELECT T1.ITEMID,
    T1.ITEMTYPE,
    T1.PURCHMODEL,
    T1.HEIGHT,
    T1.WIDTH,
    T1.SALESMODEL,
    T1.COSTGROUPID,
    T1.REQGROUPID,
    T1.EPCMANAGER,
    T1.PRIMARYVENDORID,
    T1.NETWEIGHT,
    T1.DEPTH,
    T1.UNITVOLUME,
    T1.BOMUNITID,
    T1.ITEMPRICETOLERANCEGROUPID,
    T1.DENSITY,
    T1.COSTMODEL,
    T1.USEALTITEMID,
    T1.ALTITEMID,
    T1.MATCHINGPOLICY,
    T1.INTRACODE,
    T1.PRODFLUSHINGPRINCIP,
    T1.MINIMUMPALLETQUANTITY,
    T1.PBAITEMAUTOGENERATED,
    T1.WMSARRIVALHANDLINGTIME,
    T1.BOMMANUALRECEIPT,
    T1.PHANTOM,
    T1.INTRAUNIT,
    T1.BOMLEVEL,
    T1.BATCHNUMGROUPID,
    T1.AUTOREPORTFINISHED,
    T1.ORIGCOUNTRYREGIONID,
    T1.STATISTICSFACTOR,
    T1.ALTCONFIGID,
    T1.STANDARDCONFIGID,
    T1.PRODPOOLID,
    T1.PROPERTYID,
    T1.ABCTIEUP,
    T1.ABCREVENUE,
    T1.ABCVALUE,
    T1.ABCCONTRIBUTIONMARGIN,
    T1.COMMISSIONGROUPID,
    T1.SALESPERCENTMARKUP,
    T1.SALESCONTRIBUTIONRATIO,
    T1.SALESPRICEMODELBASIC,
    T1.NAMEALIAS,
    T1.PRODGROUPID,
    T1.PROJCATEGORYID,
    T1.GROSSDEPTH,
    T1.GROSSWIDTH,
    T1.GROSSHEIGHT,
    T1.STANDARDPALLETQUANTITY,
    T1.QTYPERLAYER,
    T1.SORTCODE,
    T1.SERIALNUMGROUPID,
    T1.ITEMBUYERGROUPID,
    T1.TAXPACKAGINGQTY,
    T1.WMSPALLETTYPEID,
    T1.ORIGSTATEID,
    T1.WMSPICKINGQTYTIME,
    T1.TARAWEIGHT,
    T1.PACKAGINGGROUPID,
    T1.SCRAPVAR,
    T1.SCRAPCONST,
    T1.ITEMDIMCOSTPRICE,
    T1.FORECASTDMPINCLUDE,
    T1.PRODUCT,
    T1.PALLETTAGGING,
    T1.ITEMTAGGINGLEVEL,
    T1.DEFAULTDIMENSION,
    T1.BOMCALCGROUPID,
    T1.PBAITEMCONFIGURABLE,
    T1.PBAINVENTITEMGROUPID,
    T1.PBAHIDEDIALOG,
    T1.PBAHIDEAPPROVAL,
    T1.PBAAUTOSTART,
    T1.PBAMANDATORYCONFIG,
    T1.PDSFREIGHTALLOCATIONGROUPID,
    T1.PDSITEMREBATEGROUPID,
    T1.PDSVENDORCHECKITEM,
    T1.PMFPLANNINGITEMID,
    T1.PMFPRODUCTTYPE,
    T1.PMFYIELDPCT,
    T1.BATCHMERGEDATECALCULATIONMETHOD,
    T1.MODIFIEDDATETIME,
    T1.DEL_MODIFIEDTIME,
    T1.MODIFIEDBY,
    T1.CREATEDDATETIME,
    T1.DEL_CREATEDTIME,
    T1.CREATEDBY,
    T1.RECVERSION,
    T1.PARTITION,
    T1.RECID,
    T2.UOMSEQGROUPID,
    T2.MAXPICKQTY,
    T2.ITEMID,
    T2.RFDESCRIPTION1,
    T2.RFDESCRIPTION2,
    T2.PACKSIZECATEOGRYID,
    T2.FILTERCODE,
    T2.FILTERCODE2_,
    T2.FILTERCODE3_,
    T2.FILTERCODE4_,
    T2.FILTERGROUP,
    T2.FILTERGROUP2_,
    T2.FILTERCHANGED,
    T2.PRODQTY,
    T2.PHYSDIMID,
    T2.PACKAGECLASSID,
    T2.PICKWCNEG,
    T2.MODIFIEDDATETIME,
    T2.MODIFIEDBY,
    T2.RECVERSION,
    T2.PARTITION,
    T2.RECID,
    T3.ITEMDATAAREAID,
    T3.MODELGROUPID,
    T3.ITEMID,
    T3.MODELGROUPDATAAREAID,
    T3.RECVERSION,
    T3.PARTITION,
    T3.RECID,
    T4.ITEMID,
    T4.ITEMDATAAREAID,
    T4.ITEMGROUPID,
    T4.ITEMGROUPDATAAREAID,
    T4.RECVERSION,
    T4.PARTITION,
    T4.RECID,
    T5.TRACKINGDIMENSIONGROUP,
    T5.ITEMID,
    T5.ITEMDATAAREAID,
    T5.RECVERSION,
    T5.PARTITION,
    T5.RECID,
    T6.STORAGEDIMENSIONGROUP,
    T6.ITEMID,
    T6.ITEMDATAAREAID,
    T6.RECVERSION,
    T6.PARTITION,
    T6.RECID,
    T7.PRODUCTMASTER,
    T7.RETAITOTALWEIGHT,
    T7.VARIANTCONFIGURATIONTECHNOLOGY,
    T7.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE,
    T7.DISPLAYPRODUCTNUMBER,
    T7.SEARCHNAME,
    T7.PRODUCTTYPE,
    T7.MODIFIEDBY,
    T7.RECVERSION,
    T7.RELATIONTYPE,
    T7.PARTITION,
    T7.RECID,
    T8.DEFAULTSITE,
    T8.EQUIVALENTFACTOR,
    T8.FOESEARCHTEXT,
    T8.ITEMID,
    T8.ITEMPRICEGROUPID,
    T8.ITEMSTATUS,
    T8.MASTERITEMID,
    T8.PACKSIZE,
    T8.PURCH_MANDATORYFIXEDASSET,
    T8.PURCH_SPECIFICTEXT,
    T8.MODIFIEDDATETIME,
    T8.CREATEDDATETIME,
    T8.RECVERSION,
    T8.PARTITION,
    T8.RECID,
    T9.PRODUCTDIMENSIONGROUP,
    T9.RECVERSION,
    T9.RECID,
    T10.NAME,
    T10.RECVERSION,
    T10.RECID,
    T11.NAME,
    T11.RECVERSION,
    T11.RECID 
FROM  INVENTTABLE T1 LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN WHSINVENTTABLE T2 ON (((T2.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND (T2.DATAAREAID='abr')) 
    AND (T1.ITEMID=T2.ITEMID)) LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN INVENTMODELGROUPITEM T3 ON ((T3.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND ((T1.ITEMID=T3.ITEMID) 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID=T3.ITEMDATAAREAID))) LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN INVENTITEMGROUPITEM T4 ON ((T4.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND ((T1.ITEMID=T4.ITEMID) 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID=T4.ITEMDATAAREAID))) LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN ECORESTRACKINGDIMENSIONGROUPITEM T5 ON ((T5.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND ((T1.ITEMID=T5.ITEMID) 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID=T5.ITEMDATAAREAID))) LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN ECORESSTORAGEDIMENSIONGROUPITEM T6 ON ((T6.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND ((T1.ITEMID=T6.ITEMID) 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID=T6.ITEMDATAAREAID))) CROSS 
JOIN ECORESPRODUCT T7 LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN MARINVENTTABLE T8 ON (((T8.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND (T8.DATAAREAID='abr')) 
    AND (T1.ITEMID=T8.ITEMID)) LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN ECORESPRODUCTDIMENSIONGROUPPRODUCT T9 ON ((T9.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND (T7.RECID=T9.PRODUCT)) LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION T10 ON ((T10.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND ((T10.LANGUAGEID='en-gb') 
    AND (T7.RECID=T10.PRODUCT))) LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN ECORESPRODUCTDIMENSIONGROUP T11 ON ((T11.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND (T9.PRODUCTDIMENSIONGROUP=T11.RECID)) 
WHERE ((T1.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID='abr')) 
    AND ((T7.PARTITION=5637144576) 
    AND (T1.PRODUCT=T7.RECID)) 
    ORDER BY T1.ITEMID OPTION(FAST 6)
```

With STATISTICS IO ON I get the following stats:

```
(2849 row(s) affected)
Table 'ECORESPRODUCTDIMENSIONGROUP'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5699, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION'. Scan count 0, logical reads 8734, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ECORESPRODUCTDIMENSIONGROUPPRODUCT'. Scan count 2849, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'MARINVENTTABLE'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5885, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ECORESSTORAGEDIMENSIONGROUPITEM'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5885, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ECORESTRACKINGDIMENSIONGROUPITEM'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5885, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'INVENTITEMGROUPITEM'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5885, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'INVENTMODELGROUPITEM'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5885, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'WHSINVENTTABLE'. Scan count 2849, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ECORESPRODUCT'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5885, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'INVENTTABLE'. Scan count 1, logical reads 554, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I thought I would take a look at the ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION table as it had the most reads.  On that table are the following indexes already:

```
/****** Object:  Index [I_6869PRODUCTLANGUAGEIDX]    Script Date: 04/08/2014 15:56:37 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [I_6869PRODUCTLANGUAGEIDX] ON [dbo].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION]
(
    [PARTITION] ASC,
    [PRODUCT] ASC,
    [LANGUAGEID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


/****** Object:  Index [I_6869RECIDPRODUCTLANGUAGEID]    Script Date: 04/08/2014 15:48:15 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [I_6869RECIDPRODUCTLANGUAGEID] ON [dbo].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION]
(
    [PARTITION] ASC,
    [RECID] ASC,
    [PRODUCT] ASC,
    [LANGUAGEID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION] ADD  CONSTRAINT [I_6869RECID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [RECID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I had thought that if I create a new NC index like the following I would seen an improvement.  My thinking being that the there would be less pages to navigate however it made no difference.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Test] ON [dbo].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION]
(
    [PARTITION] ASC,
    [PRODUCT] ASC,
    [LANGUAGEID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (NAME,
    RECVERSION,
    RECID)
```

I then accidentally created an index as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Test] ON [dbo].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION]
(
    LANGUAGEID ASC,
    PRODUCT ASC

)
INCLUDE (NAME,
    RECVERSION,
    RECID)
```

And I got 3k less logical reads for that table.  Why is this more efficient?  Is it to do with the clustered information being in the leaf level of the NC index already?

Comment: Can you post the execution plan with and without the last index?

Comment: OK here we go: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11680929/Plans/WithIndex.sqlplan  and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11680929/Plans/WithoutIndex.sqlplan